# Sum Balance by Student

Tags: sql, oracle

Hello I have a simple report that show student's outstanding balances. I would like to know what is the easier way to group the result by student and show a total amount owed? I tried using group by but didn't work. I added a picture with sample daa

```
SELECT f.SchoolID as School,
st.lastfirst as Name,
st.grade_level as Grade,
f.Fee_Type_Name as Fee Type,
f.description as Description,
f.fee_amount as Fee Amount,
f.fee_paid as Fee Paid,
f.fee_Balance as Balance
FROM PS.FEE f
LEFT OUTER JOIN STUDENTS ST
ON f.StudentID = st.ID
WHERE (f.SCHOOLID=%param1%) AND (st.ENROLL_STATUS=0) AND (f.YEARID=%param2%) AND f.fee_balance >0
ORDER BY st.LASTFIRST
```

Comment: And what did your `GROUP BY` clause look like?

Comment: When you tried with Group by did you include having clause?

Comment: No I just added GROUPBY st.ID but I know there's something missing that would sum all the student balance and show in another row the total amount owed. Sorry I am a beginner with SQL and trying to learn what would be the correct way to add that to my query. We use SQL Developer here but I have to add the query to the built in query system in our student information system.

Comment: Which dbms??????  The answer you get will depend on which dbms you are using.  It's useless if someone provides a solution to the wrong dbms.  SQL Server???  Oracle???  MySQL???  Postgres???  DB2???

Comment: We use Oracle here

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Answer (score 0):

First, your query is using an outer join, but the `where` clause is turning the logic back to an inner join.  An inner join makes sense in this case, so that is what you should use.

Next, if you are thinking on a per-student basis, the query should only be selecting *student* characteristics, not details about each payment.  Then, those details are what go into the `group by`.

Something like this:

```
SELECT st.lastfirst as Name, st.grade_level as Grade,
       sum(f.fee_Balance) as Balance
FROM PS.FEE f JOIN
     STUDENTS ST
     ON f.StudentID = st.ID
WHERE f.SCHOOLID = %param1% AND st.ENROLL_STATUS = 0 AND f.YEARID = %param2% AND f.fee_balance > 0
GROUP BY st.lastfirst, st.grade_level;
```

Comment: I already have a report that show the student final balance. What I was really trying to do is display each transaction that was not paid yet and the total for each student. Some students only have one row so it doesn't really matter but for students with multiple unpaid fees I would like to show them and them show the total they owe.

Comment: @Debora. Then you should add some simulated data that looks like your tables and data. No one will do this for you. Google for Oracle running total or look for this here. This might help.